# Symfony 5 Error with a embedd form with collection one to one relation

Tags: php, symfony, one-to-one, symfony5

I am trying to embedd a form with a collection type (one to one relation) but I get the error:

Expected argument of type "App\Entity\PatientsSafeData", "array" given at property path "patiPatientsSafeData".

In the entity Patient

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\PatientsRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


class Patients
{  
    private $id;   
    private $patiLabel;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=PatientsSafeData::class, mappedBy="pasaPatient", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $patiPatientsSafeData;
```

And the entity PatientsSafeData

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\PatientsSafeDataRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


class PatientsSafeData
{
   
    private $id;

  
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Patients::class, inversedBy="patiPatientsSafeData", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $pasaPatient;
```

The formType

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;
use App\Form\PatientsSafeDataType;
use App\Entity\Patients;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class PatientsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('patiLabel',TextType::class, ["label" => "Label"])
            ->add('patiPatientsSafeData' , CollectionType::class,
                [
                    'entry_type' => PatientsSafeDataType::class,
                    'entry_options' => ['label' => 'Safe Data'],
                    'allow_add' => true
                ])
```

The template:

```
 <div class="card-body">
        <p>Save Data</p>
        <p>
            <ul class="safeData" id="safeData" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.patiPatientsSafeData.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
                {% for patSafeData in form.patiPatientsSafeData %}


                    <li>
                        {{ form_row(patSafeData.pasaName) }}
                        {{ form_row(patSafeData.pasaSurname) }}
                        {{ form_row(patSafeData.pasaDOB) }}


                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
```

I get the error saving data.
I dont know where I am wrong,
Please, any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd say, a `1-to-1` should be mapped with a simple [`EntityType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) not a collection.

Comment: otoh, you've been quite explicit with the `allow_add` option, so what you probably want is a OneToMany relationship. Point is, `CollectionType` returns an array of `SafeData`s.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem you have to create a custom form type for the patiPatientSafeData field. [Click here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html) to see how to create a custom FormType.
If you don't want to create manually the form type, you can use the symfony-cli to create a "sub" form based on the PatientSafeData Entity, then you replace CollectionType with the new FormType::class you just created.
Your PatientsType form will look like something like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('patiLabel',TextType::class, ["label" => "Label"])
            ->add('patiPatientsSafeData' , PatientSafeDataType::class)
        ;
```

Notice that i have replaced CollectionType with the new PatientSafeDataType form you're supposed to have created with the cli before.
Now your template will look like this

```
{{ form_start(patientForm) }}
    {{ form_row(patientForm.patiLabel) }}
    {{ form_row(patientForm.patiPatientsSafeData) }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
{{ form_end(patientForm) }}
```